# Start a new timer with remaining time interval

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a Timer that fires every 1.0 seconds. Every time it fires, a TimeInterval variable gets set to Date.timeSinceReferenceDate, and when I pause the timer, another TimeInterval variable also gets set to Date.timeSinceReferenceDate and the timer is invalidated.

When I press the start button again, I want it to resume from where it left off (i.e. if you paused 0.5 seconds before it fired again, it should take 0.5 seconds for it to fire when you resume, not the 1.0 it currently does).

Here's how my code looks:

```
       if (elapsedTime - beginTime) < 1.0 {
            leftoverTime = elapsedTime - beginTime
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: leftoverTime, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            let fireDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(leftoverTime)
            timer = Timer.init(fireAt: fireDate, interval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
       }
```

I imagine I need to do something with a Run Loop, but isn't there a way to just do a scheduled timer with a fire date? If I do the fire() method, it naturally only runs once and doesn't loop.

Hope someone can shine some light on this.

Thank you.

**Edit**

I have a UIViewPropertyAnimator

```
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator? = nil
```

When I start the timer, I first check if it's nil

```
animator == nil {
        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: TimeInterval(timeSec), curve: .linear) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

And then the timer starts initially

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In the method for decreasing time, I change the constraints and start the animation

```
    self.timeTrailing.constant = screenSize / 2
    self.timeLeading.constant = screenSize / 2
    animator?.startAnimation()
```

At this point it's all good, but when I then hit the pause button and pause the animation (and invalidating the timer), resuming them means they're no longer in sync. I imagine it's because you won't hit an interval of exactly 0.1 when you press it, but rather 0.03, 0.07 etc.

```
animator?.pauseAnimation()
timer?.invalidate()
```

How do I ensure that they're always synced up, no matter when and how many times you pause it before it's finished?

Comment: Just run your timer at 0.1 seconds rather than 1.0 seconds and increment a counter each time. When it gets to 10 do what you need to do and reset the counter to 0. When you pause/restart the timer, don't reset the counter and your next interval will automatically be the remaining time.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's actually really smart, hadn't thought about that. I tried it out, but it doesn't really solve the problem I'm having that I was hoping getting the timer to resume where it left off would fix.

I have an animation of a bar stretching the width of the screen that whose leading and trailing constraints are set to half the screen size, in order to meet in the middle and disappear as soon as the timer hits 00:00. If I just hit start and let it run, it works, but when I pause and resume it, it gets off track by a small amount enough to break my program. 

Check my question edit.

Comment: What if you set the leading constraint constant to the trailing constraint constant before you restart the animation?